# How to make this code better? (sinatra + datamapper)

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I'm new to this, and I'm using datamapper and sinatra to build a basic app. I have a settings page with a few text inputs for several different settings.

This page, when viewed, should pull the information from the database and populate the input boxes if they're there.

For my Setting class I have :name and :value

As of right now, I have the code working which allows a setting to be created if the name doesnt already exist, and it updates it otherwise.

```
Setting.first_or_create(:name => "seed").update(:name => "seed", :value => params[:seed])
```

3 problems:

1. if the input is blank (after the first time obviously), it overwrites it with ""
2. How can I shorten this code down? In a 'real' ruby program, should i define a method so theres not so much redundant code? I have 5 settings so i feel having that line of code 5 times with only a few things different is kind of poor. The difficulty is that I would be forced to name="" all my inputs the exact hash that i'm using. Im not sure if thats poor practice or not, or whether I should just do it all explicitly 5 times
3. In order to 'get' the data to display it i have this:

   ```
   @seed  = Setting.get(:name => "seed")
   ```

   That obviously doesn't work... what I need is to get params[:value] WHERE :name => "seed" and the use <%= @seed(???) %> to print it out. im not sure how to do this

Comment: It might be wise to validate the value of `params[:seed]` before storing it back into your database.

Comment: are all the settings saved at once (in the same method)?

Comment: i got them all to save thanks to Taryn, now I'm trying to call them in the ERB file and i cannot :/ they all appear to be nil, even though they are saved in the DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@seed = Setting.first_or_create(:name => "seed") # fetch and store
# update only if there was one
@seed.update(:name => "seed", :value => params[:seed]) if params[:seed].present?

<!-- show the value in the page -->
<%= @seed.value %>
```

Comment: undefined method `present?' for "testseed":String

Comment: In Rails? `present?` is a method added by Rails to `Object` (as in the base Object class). Every class in Rails should `respond_to(:present?)` It's the opposite of `blank?` First - check you've added the ? at the end (a typo I make from time to time). Then try `!params[:seed].blank?`

Comment: my mistake... rails shouldnt be in the tags :/ how do i check that in regular ruby?

Comment: and if that fails, then write your own: `class Object; def blank?; self.nil? || (self.respond_to?(:empty?) && !self.empty?); end; def present?; !self.blank?; end; end;`

Comment: Basically test "nil?' then "empty?" if they're both false then it's the same as "present?" if either one is false then it's "blank?"

Comment: awesome! thanks it worked :) Should I put all this in a method like def save(attr), so i can avoid typing the same thing 5 times? im not sure what is 'best' in terms of best practice

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5680/discussion-between-tallboy-and-taryn-east)

Comment: Have a look at my comment above (with class Object).  replace the ';' with actual carriage returns (cos comment-code-formatting sux) and basically you've just added the methods to the Object base class (and every class inherits from that) ;)

Comment: Er... but check that my code above actually works, of course ;) not actually bug-tested and all that ;)